# Where to put graphics processing that uses hdc in winapi classic app

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to draw a square and have the colour change every 0.1 seconds or so.

I have tried InvalidateRect and then UpdateWindow, but it only sort of works if I put it under the default case of wndProc. And then, it changes the colour a few times and stops. It also screws up all the dialog boxes to some funky shape, and the menu partially disappears. Otherwise, InvalidateRect gets called only when stuff gets clicked on, not by itself every 0.5 seconds. I tried doing a SendMessage() with WM_PAINT in the main message loop of the winMain function, but that does nothing. I think I am missing something. I could make the main window handle (hWnd) global, but not sure if that is the right way.

What is the best way to do this?

main message loop:

```
 while (windowState)
{
    
    BOOL msgState;

    iter_Count++;
    if (iter_Count >= 10) {
        
        SendMessage(nullptr, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)NULL, (LPARAM)NULL);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        iter_Count = 0;
    }

    else {
        msgState = PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);

        if (msgState) {
            windowState = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);
            msgState = false;
        }
        else {
            //msg.message = WM_PAINT; Tried this but it also doesn't work
           // DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    } 
}
```

window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
    
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case ID_SETTINGS_SETPALETTE:
            res = true;
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, set_Palette);
            break;
    
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {   
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            updater.updateImage(hdc);
            
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    }
    break;

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);//this screws up the dialog boxes and works maybe twice
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/timers).

Comment: More specifically you're looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-timers

Comment: @IInspectable Where would I start it though? I would need to regularly start and kill it.

Comment: @VroomZOOM Store the current color in a variable somewhere. Then call `SetTimer()` in the WndProc's `WM_CREATE` handler, and call `KillTimer()` in the WndProc's `WM_DESTROY` handler.  Every time the WndProc receives a `WM_TIMER` message for your timer, update the color variable as needed and invalidate the window to trigger a repaint. Every time the WndProc receives a `WM_PAINT` message, draw the square with the current color.

Answer (score 1):

Aaand... I figured out the solution. WM_TIMER sort of worked, but here is the simple code that made it work properly:

```
 case WM_CREATE:
{
    SetTimer(hWnd, 2, 100, (TIMERPROC) NULL);
    
    return TRUE;
    break;
}
case WM_TIMER:
{
    if (wParam == timerNum) {
        KillTimer(hWnd, timerNum);
        timerNum++;
        SetTimer(hWnd, timerNum, 100, NULL);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    }
           
    return FALSE;
}
```

This code successfully redraws the square every 0.1 seconds without going into uncontrollable epilepsy. I will have to reset the timerNum variable, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: You don't need to kill and set the timer on each timer event. Basically remove everything other than `InavlidateRect` (`UpdateWindow` is also not necessary) from the `WM_TIMER` case and call `KillTimer(hWnd, 2)` once in the `WM_DESTROY` case.